# Why did STL made a(nother) distinction between a std::array and a std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray, stdinitializerlist

Why is there not only 1 type with the best performance, to define a list at compile time?

The benchmark is clear, the `constexpr std::initializer_list` is faster, uses **even** less memory and the IO-reads are astonishingly less over `constexpr std::array`:

https://build-bench.com/b/1EDAcFjJ6NACk4Pg4tG2nbsEx0A

So why didn't they implement the array subscription methods to `std::initializer_list` make `std::array` unnecessary.

Comment: Have you ever felt the need to change a value in an array?

Comment: Yes. a `std::initializer_list` boils down to a `T(*)[]`, but 1 value of that C-array can also be changed... I don't get your downvote, really.

Comment: Ok, you can have my downvote after all.

Comment: [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is a tool designed for a very specific use, while [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)) has a more general purpose.

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that the posted link shows differences in ***compilation*** times of a single compiler. The runtime performances may have a different behaviour, due to quality of implementations, the actual code tested and how aggressive the optimizer could be (see e.g. [1](https://quick-bench.com/q/zDLYqT-2O-4EGSIcwWFHHbt1wgs) vs. [2](https://quick-bench.com/q/Tl2S8Ude_z5lrBtBjQea7UB9eoE)).

Comment: Yeah, bullocks, You see that it's mostly the same outcome for all compilers. You both didn't convince me yet. "general" purpose? Definition of std::array: "it a container that encapsulates fixed size arrays." -> a `initializer_list` is that too. Plus, why do we really need 2 different types that represent the same? Member function don't take any memory imo. We had a discussion on this with 4 senior developers, you can't complain neither of them, STL Is a mess.

Comment: @DrumM: "*a initializer_list is that too.*" No, it isn't. It is not an array; it is a *pointer* to an array created by the compiler. `std::array` is an actual array object with runtime storage that lives in the memory location you put it in. "*We had a discussion on this with 4 senior developers, you can't complain neither of them*" Well, they're wrong. Considering that you don't understand what `initializer_list` is, and they didn't correct you, there seems to be a lot of "wrong" to go around

Comment: @DrumM: Also, you have yet to recognize the fact that your benchmark measures *compile time performance*, not runtime performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question betrays some misunderstandings about what is going on here.

`std::array` is an array object. It is an object whose storage size is the storage for its array elements. `std::initializer_list` is a *pointer* to an array (one created by the compiler). You can heap-allocate `std::array` for example; you cannot heap-allocate `std::initializer_list`. Well, you can, but you'd just be heap allocating a pointer, which usually isn't helpful. This:

```
auto *p = new std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Is broken code, as it heap allocates a pointer to an array *temporary* created by the compiler. An array temporary that is immediately destroyed at the end of this statement. So you now have a pointer to an array that does not exist, so using `*p` or `p[x]` is undefined behavior.

Doing the same with `std::array` works fine, because `array` *is an array*.

Furthermore, the purpose of `std::initializer_list` is *not* to "define a list at compile time". As the name suggests, the point of the type is to create a list for the purpose of initializing an object. This is why the ultimate source of its data cannot be provided by any means other than a specific piece of C++ grammar, one used specifically to initialize objects: a braced-init-list.

You can use `std::initializer_list` as a quick-and-dirty way of just creating an array of values for some purpose. But that's not the point of the type. That's why it doesn't have an `operator[]`; because functions that can be initialized from a sequence of values don't tend to need that particular operation. They usually only need to walk it from beginning to end.

Comment: I all know that really... My question was more like, why couldn't they create 1 instead of 2. Why couldn't be `{1, 2, 3}` be of type `std::array` instead of `std::initializer_list`. In C you only have 1 array type, in C++ STL you have a dozen. You get a lot into implicit and explicit conversion logic which is stupid and cumbersome. Just look at other languages...

Comment: @DrumM: A braced-init-list doesn't have a type; it is a grammatical construct that initializes an object. Those 3 numbers could be the arguments to a constructor, or the initializers to a `std::array` or something else, depending on what type is being initialized by that list. As for why both types are needed, `std::initializer_list` has properties that would not be reasonable for `std::array`.

Comment: @DrumM: Or, to put it another way, there is no case where you would want to use one or the other. If you're creating a object constructor that needs to be initialized from a braced-init-list, you use `initializer_list`. If you just want an array of values, then you use `array`.